# Is there a way to to clear all the fields of an object in JAVA?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am testing a object with multiple fields. Each time am setting different attributes and testing the object .

```
 Processor processor =new Processor();
 TradeData tradeData = new TradeData();

 //case 1
 tradeData.setIndex("1");
 tradeData.setName("abc");
 processor.process(tradeData);
 Assert.assertEquals("def",tradeData.getCategory());

 //Case 2
 tradeData.setCity("1");
 tradeData.setSystem("abc");
 processor.process(tradeData);
 Assert.assertEquals("fgh",tradeData.getCategory());
```

Like wise am testing for multiple cases. Is there a way to clear the attributes of tradeData before each case. Is there a method like obj.clear() or something to do so . I dont want to declare new () object before each case.

Comment: If this is for unit testing, add a method with annotation @Before in which you initialize the class variable you use in your text.

Comment: If you keep objects between tests, would this not make the tests dependent on each other? This seems problematic.

Comment: You can use reflection, but using reflection is sheldom a good idea if there are alternatives.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to create a new object?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there are inbuilt methods to set all the fields to null. Since it's not possible i will use helper methods as suggested to set fields to null.

Comment: This still reflects bad testing practices.  You should not _need_ to reset your objects, you should just make new ones for each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

You could create a helper method in your test classes to do it, i.e.:

```
public void clearObject(TradeData tradeData)
{
   tradeData.setCity(null);
   tradeData.setSystem(null);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nice one, will make use of this.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

That is usually code smell when you are thinking about clearing an object's state within a test.

You probably should be writing tests using the [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) to setup each test.

```
Processor processor;
TradeData tradeData;

@Before 
public void initialize() {
  processor = new Processor();
  tradeData = new TradeData();
}

@Test
public void case1() {
  tradeData.setIndex("1");
  tradeData.setName("abc");
  processor.process(tradeData);
  Assert.assertEquals("def",tradeData.getCategory());
}

@Test
public void case2() {
  tradeData.setCity("1");
  tradeData.setSystem("abc");
  processor.process(tradeData);
  Assert.assertEquals("fgh",tradeData.getCategory());
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what `@Before` is for!

Comment: You don't have to use `@Before`: `Processor processor = new Processor(); TradeData tradeData = new TradeDate();` is fine, too.